# 500 SAP Internal Server Error ABAP

Tags: abap

I'am training web dynpro, and while i was testing one of my programs, an error pop-up

```
**500 SAP Internal Server Error
ERROR: Inconsistency in the dictionary for the structure WDR_TEST_SFLIGHT_RANGE. (termination: RABAX_STATE)**
```

Dose any one know what it is about? and dose any one have a solution for this erro?

regards.

Mário PT

Comment: contact your SAP basis administrator. Could be they were installing updates while you were testing. Or your structure is inactive. Either way, your admins should have a look at the short dump (ST22) that got created when you received the error. That short dump will tell you more about what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to activate the structure `WDR_TEST_SFLIGHT_RANGE` in your system again or check with the database tools if there are any differences in this structure between database and SAP system.